# MySQL query to return specific row value depending on

Tags: mysql

Re,

I have two tables. I would like to run a `SELECT` query where I would select `table1.*` and a "virtual" `columnX` that will return:

- *YES* `table1.columnB` = `table2.columnB`
- *NO* if no match is found in `table2`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   t1.*,
   (CASE WHEN t2.columnB IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as columnX
FROM
   table1 t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   table2 t2
     ON  t1.columnB = t2.columnB
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a few basic structures:

you can use a `UNION` to get these values with different where clauses,

you can use a `NVL` and `OUTER JOIN` to substitute a value when the expected column is null,

in some SQL environments, you can use `DECODE` to change the returned value

in some SQL you can use `CASE` statements.